# Using j2objc in swift framework(not static library)

Tags: objective-c, swift, j2objc

I want to import files which are translated by j2objc in `Cocoa Touch Framework` in Xcode, and get some error.

**My implementing steps as the following:**

In `PeopleProject` -> `Pepole.java`:

```
   class Pepole{
          .....
    }
```

1. Create a framework(named:`objCFrameWork`) and language is Objective-C in xcode(not static library).
   [image]
2. Config for j2objc(**Build Rules,Settings.xcconfig**)

   **Build Rules**
   [image]

**Settings.xcconfig**

[image]

3. New a file(Campony) in framework project and import People.h

   ```
    @interface Company : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic) People *CEO;
    @end
   ```
4. Add a demon(`objCFrameWorkDemo`) using the `objCFrameWork`

   ```
    Company *c = [[Company alloc] init];
    [c.CEO sayWithNSString:@"Hello"];
   ```

6.Build objCFrameWork successfully.

7.Build  objCFrameWorkDemo failed.

[image]

**The source**:https://github.com/leogeng/J2ObjC_Framework.git

Comment: Can you use any other (custom) Objective-C classes in your framework? If not, this may be unrelated to j2objc.

Comment: I  new an objc file and  it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

If the Java source (A.java) declares that it is part of a package, then the default translation requires that you include the package as a subdirectory. For example, if class A is in the foo.bar package, then the header needs to referenced as `#include "foo/bar/A.h"`.

If that won't work (Xcode doesn't support subdirectories well, so many projects avoid them), then run j2objc with the `--no-package-directories` flag to generate files that don't use subdirectories. This requires that all Java source files in the app have unique class/interface names, since there's no longer a package to differentiate them (the exception are JRE classes, which always need package subdirectories).